# How to type Greek Letter inside an itemise

Tags: itemize, greek

I'm trying to write an algorithm in a simple list format in latex.

In the first point, I need an 'alpha' symbol followed by a subscript 'out'.

This is what I did, but it doesn't seem to like it and throws several errors as well as giving strange outputs.

```
\begin{document}
    \section{Algorithm}
        \begin{footnotesize}
            \begin{itemize}[noitemsep]
                \item A maximum probability \textalpha _{out} for removal is pre-specified,
                \item Step 2...,
                \item Step 3...,
                \item Step 4...,
            \end{itemize}
        \end{footnotesize}
\end{document}
```

Before posting this, I also tried the `{textgreek}` package described [here](http://texblog.org/2012/03/15/greek-letters-in-text-without-changing-to-math-mode/), but that didn't seem to work either. I must be doing something wrong.

Is there an easy solution to implementing a list that contains special characters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `\textsubscript{out}` instead of `_`

Comment: That solves the issue with the subscript. Thanks for posting.

Comment: @Reanimation so, Uwe's comment solved you problem or there's still something not solved?

Comment: Please complete your code i.e. make it so it compiles by adding `\documentclass...` etc. This makes it easier to help and ensures that your question is useful to others. Note that the uninitiated may well be unable to fill in the gaps. For example, I don't know how to make your code compile. I got past the first error by adding `enumitem` but I've no idea about the second. So if I wanted to achieve the same effect, this question would be useless to me because it omits essential pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: Ok, I'll update my code in a sec. Yes there is still an issue with the alpha sign. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the alpha why not just use `$\alpha_{out}$`, or `$\alpha_{\mbox{out}}$` or `$\alpha_{\text{out}}$` or...

Comment: Ah nice! Problem solved. Thanks for posting. `$\alpha_{out}$` works great.

Comment: It seem more appropriate to use `$\alpha_{\text{out}}$` (with the inclusion of `\usepackage{amsmath}` in your preamble).

Answer (score 3):

Using `textgreek` is fine to have greek letter in text mode is you have an updated installation with this package installed. Other options are use `inputenc` to use the unicode character or even `babel`. See also the packages `upgreek` and `textgreek`. For the subscript you can use `\textsubscript` as commented, using `fixltx2e`, or a `\raisebox` without additional packages, or in math mode `_{\text{}}` with the `amsmath` package as Werner said, or `_{\textrm{}}` with the `amstext` package. Example:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}  % for 1st solution, no math mode
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}        % for 2nd solution, no math mode
\usepackage{fixltx2e, textgreek}   % for 3rd solution, no math mode
\usepackage{amstext,upgreek}       % for 4th solution, math mode
\usepackage{amstext,txfonts}       % for 5th solution, "fake" text mode
\def\alphaout{\ensuremath\alphaup\raisebox{-.3ex}{\scriptsize out}}

\begin{document}

{\greektext a}\raisebox{-.3ex}{\scriptsize out}  

α\raisebox{-.3ex}{\scriptsize out} 

\textalpha\textsubscript{out} 

$\upalpha_{\textrm{out}}$

\alphaout

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hello @Fran. Is there a simple way to obtain greek alphabet? I tried with \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*], but it give me the classic alphabet: a, b, c...

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi Try with `\begin{enumerate}[label=\selectlanguage{greek}\alph*]` (of course with babel loaded as in the MWE and `enumitem` package).

Comment: I tried your solution and the statement \usepackage[italian,greek]{babel} transforms also italian letters in greek leters. How can I select italian language for the text?

Comment: Try `greek, italian` instead of `italian,greek`